# Mechanism of Future objects in Dart

Tags: dart

Can somebody explane me how does it works when callback returns some type, object Future turns to Future<returned by callback type>? What mechanism of this?

```
Future<String> myFuture = Future(() {
    return "Hello Future";
});
```

Comment: What details do you want that is not already specified in the documentation? https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.0/dart-async/Future/Future.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Dart infers the type argument to the `Future` constructor is just called *type inference*.
When you invoke a constructor of a generic class, you need to specify the type arguments (you cannot create a generic *instance*), but Dart allows you to do so implicitly.
In this case:

```dart
Future<String> myFuture = Future(() {
    return "Hello Future";
});
```

the "context type" for the constructor invocation, the type of value that the context expects the expression to have, is `Future<String>`. Since the constructor of the generic class `Future<T>` creates a `Future<T>`, it's easy to infer that you must mean `= Future<String>(...);`.

Type inference isn't magic. It uses clues from the context or, if there is no context expectation, clues from the arguments to figure out what the missing type arguments must be. Sometimes there is no best guess, and sometimes the algorithm is just a little too simple to find a solution, but most of the time, it just works.

Comment: But why code `class some1<T>  {T id;  some(this.id)}
void main(){
var a = some1(() => 'Hello Future');
 }`  will return object with type som1<String Function> but not some1<String> like with Future?